# Spring Batch job metadata persistence issue

Tags: database, spring, spring-batch, hsqldb

We use Spring Batch to write our jobs and it works absolutely fine. But recently we saw an issue with the truncation that lead to some questions as to how spring batch stores meta data about the job.

1. Each time a job runs spring batch stores the meta data about the job in the db. There are 2 tables: batch_step_execution_context and batch_job_execution_context that are saving the meta data in 2 columns short_context and serialized_context. Both these columns save the exact data but short_context has a limit of 2500 characters and so the data is truncated.

Why do we 2 columns for storing the exact data, if we get rid of short_context what implications can it on the jobs

2. Right now we use an in memory HSQL db for our jobs. One of our job threw the following exception:

   org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [UPDATE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT SET SHORT_CONTEXT = ?, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT = ? WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ?]; data exception: string data, right truncation; nested exception is java.sql.SQLDataException: data exception: string data, right truncation

More stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: data exception: string data, right truncation
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.types.CharacterType.castOrConvertToType(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.types.CharacterType.convertToType(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.getUpdatedData(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.executeUpdateStatement(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.getResult(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
```

Is this specific to HSQL db, because it works fine for other jobs, i.e. it is truncating it properly

thanks

Comment: serialized_context is not 2500 variable length character field, short_context is serialized_context is a text field

Answer (score 0):

The `serialized_context` column should be a `CLOB` (or `LONGVARCHAR` in HSQLDB), not a 2500 variable-length character field. Check the DDL [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql). If you change the datatype in your HSQLDB database, you should not see any truncation.

Beyond that, I would caution you from serializing too much in the execution context as it can severely impact performance. What is it you're storing that's so big?

Comment: its actually spring batch that saves meta data in the db. So when you are passing objects form one step to another after each step execution the state of the object os persisted in the db. At the end job execution context table will have the entire state of all the objects that were passed during the job. Also as I said serialized_context is text and short_context is character varying (2500) field. But i am not sure why we need both the fields since they are saving the same data

Comment: The `serialized_context` column should **NOT** be 2500 characters. It is meant to be a CLOB/Text/Longvarchar object and is only used as overflow in the event that the serialized data is larger than 2500 characters. Still, why are you passing so many objects (or a few very large objects) via the context? In the 100+ batch jobs we use in my office, we never have needed to leverage the larger `serialized_context` column. In fact, doing so requires registering a LOB handler when creating your job repository bean.

Comment: We are using Tasklet as a Step in the job, so say when we read from the db that is one step and then writing to some other data source is another data source. So in this case we pass the objects read form the db step to the other step and these objects might have variable size.

Comment: It's nonstandard to pass large amounts of information between steps using the job execution context, so I would question why you would pass your data in such a way. Why not just use a `StepExecutionListener` in the following step and make a service call from the `beforeStep()` method?

Comment: I am going to explore that